# Ansible: set_children is not working with a variable

Tags: xml, ansible

I am attempting to modify a simple xml file via ansible.

simple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<controller-info>
  <controller-host></controller-host>
  <controller-port></controller-port>
  <controller-ssl-enabled></controller-ssl-enabled>
</controller-info>
```

playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - xml_vars.yml
  tasks:
  - name: modify xml file
    xml:
      path: /home/user/simple.xml
      xpath: /controller-info
      set_children: "{{ controller_conf }}"
```

xml_vars.yml

```
---
controller_conf:
    - controller-host: "localhost"
    - controller-port: "443"
    - controller-ssl-enabled: "true"
```

when I run the playbook, I receive the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to localhost closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554463945.2-8302647655843/AnsiballZ_xml.py\", line 113, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554463945.2-8302647655843/AnsiballZ_xml.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554463945.2-8302647655843/AnsiballZ_xml.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_RSmDlG/__main__.py\", line 868, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_RSmDlG/__main__.py\", line 844, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_RSmDlG/__main__.py\", line 408, in set_target_children\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_RSmDlG/__main__.py\", line 386, in set_target_children_inner\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_RSmDlG/__main__.py\", line 657, in children_to_nodes\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_RSmDlG/__main__.py\", line 645, in child_to_element\r\n  File \"lxml.etree.pyx\", line 921, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:41344)\r\n  File \"apihelpers.pxi\", line 660, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:18894)\r\n  File \"apihelpers.pxi\", line 1333, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:24601)\r\nTypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'int'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

If I change the playbook to the following, it works fine:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - xml_vars.yml
  tasks:
  - name: modify xml file
    xml:
      path: /home/user/simple.xml
      xpath: /controller-info
      set_children: 
        - controller-host: "localhost"
        - controller-port: "443"
        - controller-ssl-enabled: "true"
```

I am at a loss as to why this isn't working. I am sure it is something simple I am overlooking. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. the issue was actually caused by a  in the variables at the end of the controller_conf: line. Once removed, everything worked correctly